# The problem with "there"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, phrase-usage, subject-verb-inversion, construction

> It is natural, now, to think of there being connected with a sign, also what I should like to call the sense of the sign.

It's the first sentence of the paragraph. There wasn't a context about some place (so "there" isn't referring to the place).

I'm asking why is it "connected" instead of "connection"?

I asked this because I think "There being" is the form of "there is". Am I right at this point at least?

Explain to me, please, the syntax of this sentence and especially the author's usage of "there".

Comment: You should include a link or reference to the original article.

Comment: Googling, I found the sentence. And the version you quote ***leaves out*** the parenthetical phrase in the middle of the sentence.  Further, where I found it, there's context ... it's ***not*** the first sentence of the article. You clearly have a version where somebody has altered the original sentence and taken it out of context. This is why it doesn't make any sense any more.

Comment: That is a quote from a translation of Frege's work. Certainly worth mentioning. And it is in the middle of the translation I found. https://sites.uni.edu/boedeker/reference.pdf

Comment: Probably "think of there being" = "think that there is"

Comment: I'd prefer the 'also' to be repositioned (the German influence probably led to the original placement): "It is natural, now, to think of there also being connected with a sign what I should like to call _the sense_ of the sign." I'd take 'think of there being ...' to mean 'adopt the model of a sign having a "sense" '.

Comment: @Edwin. Yes, your rendering captures the essence of the original: "_Es liegt nun nahe, mit einem Zeichen (Namen, Wortverbindung, Schriftzeichen) außer dem Bezeichneten, was die Bedeutung des Zeichens heißen möge, noch das verbunden zu denken, was ich den Sinn des Zeichens nennen möchte, worin die Art des Gegebenseins enthalten ist._"

Comment: The fragment quoted is unintelligible to me. Why would anyone think this is a suitable question for this site? And then it transpires that it is a translation from the German — Into what language, I wonder.

Comment: Could someone narrow down where to find the quote? The PDF isn't searchable.

Comment: @KillingTime Stop telling people here what they should do.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him Why not? You are.

Comment: @Barmar. It is the first sentence of the second paragraph on page 57 of the .pdf file linked to above.

Comment: @Shoe Well, not really, because the English *also*-NP must come after the "in addition to"_NP  and thus couldn't ever be in the post-BE position which precedes both the noun phrases involved!

Comment: @Shoe: how do you understand *noch **das verbunden** zu denken*?

Comment: @TimR. It needs to be analysed together with its following clause: _noch __das__ verbunden zu denken, __was__ ich den Sinn des Zeichens nennen möchte_.  The English equivalent of _das...was_ is _that which_. So the extract here means _also consider to be connected with that which I would like to call the meaning of the sign_.  Disclaimer: I am neither a philosopher nor a translator, so I hope that either one or other of these can join the thread and provide reliable elucidation.

Comment: @Shoe  Thanks. Fair to say that you've added "to be" and "with that" for the sake of  clarity and fluidity in English, and that if we were to translate it "raw"  it would be "**consider connected** that which I would like to call the meaning of the sign"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer. Tldr:**

The noun phrase that we would normally expect after the verb *be* in an existential construction has been moved to the end of the clause. In this particular case this means that the verb *BE* is followed by an adjective phrase instead of a noun phrase.

---

**The full story:**

> 1. It is natural, now, to think of there being **connected** with a sign, what I should like to call the sense of the sign.

The Original Poster's version includes the word *also*, which I've removed. The reason I've removed it is that the Original Poster's example is an extract from a much longer sentence, and the word *also* does not make sense without the missing material.

Now, the Original Poster is concerned about the word *connected* and is asking why it is not the word *connection*. To see why one might expect a noun like *connection* here consider the following example which has the important elements we are concerned with without the fluff:

> 2. There is connected with a sign, the sense of that sign.

And now consider the following example:

> 3. There was a bomb attached to the prisoner.

Here we see an existential sentence with all its parts in the normal order. First we have the grammatical subject, the dummy subject *there*. Then, afterwards, the verb *BE* (here the word *was*). And then we have the 'displaced subject', namely the noun phrase *a bomb*. Occurring right after this is an adjective phrase, which we could be forgiven for thinking is part of a noun phrase  "a bomb attached to the prisoner". Actually this adjective phrase is a separate complement of the verb *BE*, as we are about to see.

According to the canonical order of items within an existential clause exemplified above, it is perfectly normal to expect a noun phrase after the verb *BE*. However, when the displaced subject in an existential clause represents new information and is more interesting/informative than the other complement of the verb *BE*, it often gets postposed. In other words, it gets moved to the very end of the clause. And if you look at (3), you will se that *a bomb* must be new because it has the indefinite article *a*, which we use when introducing a thing that hasn't been previously discussed. We can also infer that *attached to the prisoner* includes mention of a previously discussed prisoner. We can infer this because we **normally** use the word *the* to refer to things or people that we have previously discussed. For these reasons, example (3) would arguably be just as good, if not much better, if the information was repackaged as follows:

> 4. There was attached to the prisoner, a bomb.

Here the NP (noun phrase) *a bomb* occurs in the focal position at the end of the clause where it has more dramatic effect. But notice too, that this means that the phrase after the verb *BE* is no longer an NP, but an adjective phrase. If we were not familiar with this kind of repackaging, we might think that the word after *was* should be a noun like *attachment* as opposed to an adjective like *attached*.

This same repackaging of the information in order to put the most important information at the end of the clause is what is happening in the Original Poster's example. The less effective but more conventional way of phrasing example (2) would be:

> 5. There is the sense of a sign attached to a sign.

Notice that, with this less effective but more conventional word order, the phrase after the verb *BE* is in indeed a noun phrase, not an adjective.

Executive summary (as John Lawler used to say): "there" ain't no problem there.

It's interesting, grammar, isn't it?

Comment: +1! I think what's confusing about this sentence is the extra comma before "also" (or "what" in your version). While it may reflect prosody, it makes it much less obvious that  "also what I should like to call the sense of the sign" is a postposing construction rather than a supplement of some sort.

Comment: @alphabet Agreed.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Sorry for the vagueness of the question itself, it's because I can in the most part only read in English, not write.

Comment: @Sayber73 No problem, nice first question.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him Yes, voting to reopen.

Comment: You don't actually explain the *form* "there being".

Comment: @Lambie No, because it's incidental to the OP's main concern, which is about the *form* of the word "connected". [But it's because the clause is the complement of the preposition *of*.]

Comment: I thought it was there, clearly: Explain to me, please, the syntax of this sentence and **especially the author's usage of "there"**.

Comment: @Lambie OP was evidently worried that this might be a different *there* from the "there is"-*there*, and that this might be causing the *connected* instead of the expected *connection*. It's evident from my answer that a) this is the same there and b) it being a different *there* (which it isn't)  bears no relation to why we have *connected* instead of *connection*. OP's question proper: **I'm asking why is it "connected" instead of "connection?"**

Comment: I think you are going about it backwards. This: "there being connected with a sign" could not be followed by the word connection and maintain grammaticality with the rest of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

This is merely one of the cases of the possible forms of the idiom "there < to be >  connected". In this particular clause it is the *-ing*-participle that is used in an *-ing*-clause.

- there is connected
- there was connected
- there will be connected
- there being connected
- there wouldn't be connected
- there could be connected
- …

It is  similar to a sentence such as follows, in which it becomes somewhat easier to make out the grammar. (Do not try to give this sentence  a meaning in context, it is just--semantically and grammatically--a plausible construction that aims at highlighting a parallel.)

- It is natural, now, to think of *a concept* being connected with a sign, also what I should like to call the sense of the sign. ("Concept" *is now the subject instead of* "there".)

"There being connected with a sign" is the direct object of the phrasal verb "to think of"; this is possible because noun phrases are naturally objects and that a nominal clause has mostly the properties of a noun phrase (it is much like a noun phrase as far as what it stands for semantically).

> It is natural, now, to think of there being connected with a sign, also what I should like to call the sense of the sign.

*An equivalent formulation*

It is natural, now, to think that  there exists in connection with a sign, also what I should like to call the sense of the sign.

Comment: You put in that formulation après coup.

Answer (score -1):

A translation from German of a paper called *On Sense and Reference* by Frege.

It is natural, now, to think of there being [of the fact that there is] connected with a sign (name, combination of words, letter), besides that to which the sign refers, which may be called the reference of the sign, also what I should like to call the *sense* of the sign, wherein the mode of presentation is contained.

*there being*, e.i. the fact there is, *being* is a gerund:

- Besides there being [the fact there is] five criminals in the jail, [there is] also, what I want to call dimwits in the dock.

It is natural, now, to think of there being connected with a sign (name, combination of words, letter), [...]  also what I should like to call the *sense* of the sign [...],

Today, this might be translated like this:

It is natural, now, to think of what I should like to call the sense of the sign as connected with a sign (name, combination of words, letter).

Comment: Gerunds are used like nouns; "being", here, is not used like a noun.

Comment: @LPH gerund or participle there is no much difference here.

Comment: There might exist such a terminology, but in this sentence "being" does not have the place of a noun: "there" is subject.

Comment: @LPH It doesn't much matter because it still needs translating. It just is not a big deal AND I SAID: gerund OR participle.

Comment: Then why is it "connected" and not "connection"? Isn't "there's connected" incorrect?

Comment: @LPH If you believe that there is a difference between gerunds and participles (I, Iike many grammarians, don't), then *being* is most definitely a gerund here. It is heading the 'gerundial clause' "there being connected". It has to be a 'gerundial' clause because it is occurring as the complement of the preposition "of".

Comment: +1 for giving the source and quoting more context.

Comment: @Sayber73 Because of the unusual word order. Usually, one says: X is connected **to B. But here, first, there is "is connected *with*". So, *usually**, one would write: the sign is connected with the sense of the sign. But due to the "there being", it became for the translator: there being connected with the sign// *also what I woud like to call*// the sense of the sign*. However, the meaning is the same as: there being connected the sense of the sign with the sign.

Comment: @LPH *There might exist such a terminology* hmm. Sounds French to me. Anyway, Araucaria - Him has put this straight.